# App crashes when trying to call SetSupportActionBar

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-support-library

I have made an app that works fine and uses a default toolbar. However I want to add navigation buttons to this toolbar so I am implementing my own that I can inflate a menu onto it. However when I try to call SetSupportActionBar() the app crashes.

I have tried to set the app to not use the default action bar in both the manifest: `<activity android:name=".MainMenu" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"/>` as well as in the XML file: `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"`, as this was the suggested solution for someone else with a similar issue however this has not worked.

The code I am using is as follows;
XML:

```
<Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Java:

```
public class MainMenu extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar mToolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
        mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.menu_arrow);
        mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, next time, when mentioning that something crashes, please include a stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the toolbar's xml to:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

instead of `Toolbar`
also look at your imports, if you have this line:

```
import android.widget.Toolbar;
```

replace it with:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```